# Grabbing arraylist of objects from servlet

Tags: java, jsp

I have an arraylist of objects in my servlet where I want to call it in my jsp file. I'm not sure how to go about doing this.

inside my servlet I have:

`public ArrayList <Song> searchedSongs = new ArrayList <Song> ();`

where the object is a Song.java file. Inside my jsp file I have:

```
<strong style="color: #ff9642;">CART:</strong><br/>    
<% ArrayList<Song> results = (ArrayList<Song>) session.getAttribute("results"); %>
<% out.print(results.size()); %> items
```

I am getting an error saying my `Song cannot be resolved`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should import the class in you JSP

```
<%@ page import="com.entity.Song" %>
```

You might refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/239147/how-do-you-import-classes-in-jsp)

Comment: I did add it to the top of my JSP file