# cannot be resolved to a type (jsp + eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, types

I have a jsp proyect as a presentation layer to show the result (a simple string) from a function from a java class. This class is in the src directory.

When I try to run I get this errors:

> org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile  class for JSP:

and then:

> parser cannot be resolved to a type

My jsp code is:

```
<%
        String input="ebnf a{non terminal A;}";
        Symbol tree=null;
        parser p=null;
        InputStream entrada=null;
        analex analizador;
        try{
            entrada=new ByteArrayInputStream(input.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            analizador=new analex(entrada);
            p=new parser(analizador);
            tree=p.parse();
        }catch(Exception e){
            out.println("ERROR");
        }
        finally{}
        out.println("CORRECTO");
        ConDiaCClass cdc=Singleton.getInstance();
        out.println(cdc);
%>
```

Actually I get the same problem with ConDiaCClass and analex classes too.

I have not created these class with Eclipse. They are from another project but they both are placed in the src directory (where the java classes are suposed to be). It seems that the jsp cannot recognize them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally it was just that the classes hadn't got the visibility atribute. I had not the public attribute for them so they could not be resolved as a type although the jsp knew where they are.

That was a JFlex/CUP problem: JFlex & CUP creates classes (analex & parser) without a visibility attribute.

Thank you for you answers. Next time I'll try to be more specific with my questions.

Answer (score 7):

You should [add the necessary import statement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/239293/1065197)s at the beginning of the jsp. A sample:

```
<%@ page import="java.util.List" %>
<%@ page import="yourpackage.parser, yourpackage.analex" %> //and on
```

An advice: make your classes follow the [Java Code Conventions proposed by Oracle](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html). It is a good guide to help other people to read easily your code (it will help yourself when you want to review/improve the code).

Comment: Doesn't work. I had my imports done. I should have said that. Sorry.

Comment: Try to comment the code and compile your jsp. If that works, then copy your code into another class and test it to know it runs. After that, make your all the imports you need are in your class. Also, by the description you're giving, it looks like `parser` is not even a class but looks like an attribute for a class.

Answer (score 7):

Clean the project,and reload the JRE as follows: 
Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Add Library -> JRE System Library

Answer (score 1):

Just to add more on above answer.

`JasperException` is the super class of all the exceptions thrown by JSP Engine. When your run JSP first time Tomcat Engine compiles your JSP and may throw compile time error which you are getting.

Read more [JasperException](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-4.1-doc/jasper/docs/api/org/apache/jasper/JasperException.html)

> where the java classes are suposed to be

Your classes should be under `/WEB-INF/classes` directory. By default  `/WEB-INF/classes` and `/WEB-INF/lib` (Third party APIs) directory comes under `CLASSPATH`

So, If you have package `foo.bar` under `src` direcotry, Then your class goes at `/WEB-INF/classes/foo/bar/`

Comment: @AegLos: Provide complete error stacktrace.Always provide sufficient details so that users can help you.