# How import a .java file into a JSP page?

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, tomcat

this is my first time trying to use java for backend web systems.

I have been reading up some guides on how to do this, and thus far i understand the following points:

1. I am not allowed to import .java files, but rather, import the class files.
2. <%@ page language="java" import="somefile.*"%>  this is how i import a package.
3. After importing a package, I am required to create an instance of the class.

However, I am confused with a few things.

I now have a Dynamic Web Project, developing in Eclipse IDE and using TomCat7.0 apache.

I have a directory
Java_Resources/src/somepackage/

and some .java files in the above directory.

Question 1, in Eclipse, when I run these files, they are automatically compiled. Where does these class files go?

Question 2, when I run the following code, I recieved some errors. What am I doing wrong? Is it because I do not have my class files in the right directory?

```
<%@ page language="java" import="twitter.*"%>

<%
    JavaFile jf = new Javafile();

    String result = jf.searchTweets("someString");
    System.out.println(result);
%>
```

Error report:

```
type Exception report

message

description The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /hello.jsp at line 10

7: <%@ page language="java" import="twitter.*"%>
8: 
9: <%
10:     Javafile jf = new JavaFile();
11:     
12:     String result = jf.searchTweets("someString");
13:     System.out.println(result);
```

Thank you for your time and effort.

note: I have read the following links, but they do not seem to provide a solution on how to write your own .java files and import these classes into your jsp files.

http://www.jsptut.com/

[How do you import classes in JSP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/239147/how-do-you-import-classes-in-jsp)

http://www.coderanch.com/t/288534/JSP/java/importing-class-file-jsp

EDIT: I found my own answer.

This is my original directory

[image]

As you can see, my WEB-INF/lib is empty.

All that was required to do, is to move the relevant .jar files into this directory.

Note: I have already imported the relevant .jar files to the Eclipse project, but it seems that I need to move them into WEB-INF/lib on top of importing them into the project.

Thank you to all that helped answer my question.

This is my final directory image[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only classes may be imported into a `.java` file, and a JSP "compiles" to a `.java` file, so this requirement holds for JSP files too.

From a quick glance at the API, it seems that your import is formatted correctly; but, you are importing the wrong namespace.  The [javadoc for the twitter4j API](http://twitter4j.org/ja/oldjavadocs/2.1.12/index.html) indicates that you should be importing "twitter4j" namespaces, not "twitter" namespaces.

Comment: twitter4j is a class i wrote myself actually. sorry for the name confusion.

Comment: Not a problem, but this is exactly why Sun recommends you add organizational information to your namespace.  For my hobby stuff, my namespaces look like `edwinbuck.twitter`, and I recommend you do something similar (`hehui.twitter`).  It is a _real pain_ to do this later because you want to import something that conflicts in namespace.

Comment: Or `org.hehui.twitter` if you end up owning `www.hehui.org` domain :) But then you don't need to own a domain to name your package like that anyway.

Comment: I've changed the question already. Same problem still exists. Do I need to create a WEB-INF/classes, and move my class files there?

Comment: Yes, you do need a WEB-INF/classes, and any imports do need to be there, in subdirectories that match the namespaces.  Or if you like JAR files, a WEB-INF/lib needs to contain the JAR file that contains the imported classes.

Comment: Thanks, I got my answer, edited and placed it in my question. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

> > Question 1, in Eclipse, when I run these files, they are automatically compiled. Where does these class files go?

The class files go inside `WEB-INF/classes` directory.

> > Question 2, when I run the following code, I recieved some errors. What am I doing wrong? Is it because I do not have my class files in the right directory?

Perhaps you have forgotten to put `twitterXXX.jar` (or whatever it is called) into `WEB-INF/lib` directory.

Comment: do u mean that, something.java (a file i wrote myself), I need to create a jar file of that, and put it in WEB-INF/lib directory?

Comment: No, the twitter4j API that you're using, that comes in a JAR file, doesn't it? That goes inside the `lib` directory.

Comment: again, sorry for the confusion. twitter4j is a class i wrote myself. I'll edit the question to avoid further confusion.

Comment: Just saw your other comment. Can you show what package declaration you have for the Twitter4J class that you've written?