# Displaying Java content in JSP

Tags: java, jsp

Setup - Tomcat 6.0.16 - MacBook

I have a JSP page that is invoking a separate Java application that searches the web and returns content. I am looking to display this content on my JSP page.

My JSP code - Which invokes the below JAVA

```
System.out.println("Test3");
Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new GuiceInjector());
Run r = injector.getInstance(Run.class);
r.runSliceConsumer();
```

My JAVA -  This works and prints my content to the Terminal window.

```
if (sliceHits == null) {
    System.err.println("Timeout occurred while fetching slices");
    return;
}
if (!sliceHits.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println("Found some slices Yuhuuuu ! :-) ");
    String sliceContent = createSlices(sliceHits);
    System.out.println("sliceContent:");
    System.out.println(sliceContent);
} 
else {
    System.out.println("No Slices were found for this query");
}
```

My issue is that i want to display the content above in my JSP web page and not just the Terminal window. I assume that as the connection is made one way, my JSP invokes my JAVA that i should be able to just display the results but im having a few problems, i hope its just with my Syntax.

My attempt in JSP

```
<div id="result-page-query" align='center'>
<%
    sliceContent = createSlices(sliceHits);
    out.println(sliceContent);
%>
</div>
```

I’m not sure if I’m explaining this right, but essentially I’m trying to display the content of "sliceContent" on my Webpage

Thanks

EDIT:

Hi as suggest below by jddsantaella and Hardik Mishra I had to import the necessary packages. I then created an object in this case "kContent" and executed the method.

The solution was similar to the below

```
<%

    Run kContent = injector.getInstance(Run.class);
    kContent.runSliceConsumer();
    out.println(kContent);
%>
```

Comment: what results do you see from your attempt, using <% out.println(sliceContent) %>?

Comment: @pb2q Hey there. That gives me a Tomcat error message below with the error right at that line

"org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP:"

Comment: @dystroy: `out` is implicitly available in JSP and can be used to print like above given code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use Java code in your JSP, it is not recommendable. Anyway, you can print the value returned by a method doing something like this:

```
...
<%=myObjetct.myMethod(...)%>
...
```

In your attempt is not clear what `createSlices` is. I think it could be

```
<%=r.runSliceConsumer()%>
```

assuming that your `runSliceConsumer` method is returning something

Comment: Hi jddsantaella

I think you are on to somthing here. Ill play around with it and see what i come up with. JSP is not my strong point so ill be trying random syntax combinations

Comment: Hi jddsantaella

Just wanted to say thanks fr your help. I have posted my solution based on your suggestion above.

Answer (score 1):

It is not advised to use JAVA code in JSP. JSPs are mainly for presentation.

Second, `"org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP` is a runtime  exception. When you run a JSP and if there is a change then previously compiled JSP, your web container compiles JSP at run time.

Also, You should [add the necessary import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/239147/how-do-you-import-classes-in-jsp/239293#239293) statements at the beginning of the jsp

```
<%@ page import="java.util.List" %>

<%@ page import="yourpackage.slicer" %>
```

And Last,

```
<%
    sliceContent = createSlices(sliceHits);
    out.println(sliceContent);
%>
```

You can print String returned value from your method. Just check in calling method like `myObj.myMethod()`