# invoking java function from jsp file

Tags: java, jsp, email, exception, invoke

i'm trying to invoke a java function on a jsp page. the function is supposed to send a mail by demand.

this is the java code:

```
package s;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

        public class SendMail {

            public static void send() {

                final String username = "";
                final String password = "";

                Properties props = new Properties();
                props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
                props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
                props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
                props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

                Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
                  new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                    }
                  });

                try {

                    Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
                    message.setFrom(new InternetAddress("shov.rz@gmail.com"));
                    message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                        InternetAddress.parse("shov.rz@gmail.com"));
                    message.setSubject("Testing Subject");
                    message.setText("Dear Mail Crawler,"
                        + "\n\n No spam to my email, please!");

                    Transport.send(message);

                    System.out.println("Done");

                } catch (MessagingException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
            }

    }
```

and i'm invoking it on a jsp page:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <%@import page="s.SendMail"%>
    <%
    s.SendMail.send();
    %>
    <html>
<head>
</head>
</html>
```

it doesn't compile and the eclipse throws an exception: org.apache.jasper.JasperException
what am i doing wrong?
thank's for the help!

Comment: Since you import `s.SendMail`, you do not need to prefix with `s` anymore: `SendMail.send()` is enough. If this doesn't work, then no idea.

Comment: it didn't work... i have the same problem

Comment: take a look on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/239147/how-do-you-import-classes-in-jsp)

Comment: the import is done currectly. if i replace the send function with another function - it works.
i have trouble in invoking this specific method.

Comment: Could you post output, a stack trace or something?

Comment: Regarding to [this post](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/523793/how-solve-orgapachejasperjasperexception-javalangnullpointerexception) I suspect  a NullPointerException in your send() implementation, so check all your references (variables) which one is null.

Comment: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /reww.jsp at line 4

1: <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; 
2:     pageEncoding=UTF-8"%>
3:     <%@page import="s.SendMail" %>
4:     <%SendMail.send();%>
5:

Comment: Stacktrace:
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:505)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:398)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:342)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:267)
 javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)

Answer (score 1):

The 'page' and 'import' terms are the wrong way round. Should be:

```
    <%@ page import="s.SendMail" %>
```