# Making a JSON string or object in JSP

Tags: json, jsp

This is what I thought a very simple issue. Basically I am trying to send a json string to a REST API service. Here is the JSON they supply

```
"vslText": "[field1] = '12345678'"
```

Now to send it to the REST as a string I've tried

```
String jsonRequest = "{ 'vslText' : '[field1] = " + ""
```

But I get lost in all the quotes.

I tried using

```
JSONObject jsonRequest = new JSONObject();
jsonRequest.put("vslText", "[field1] = '12345678'");
```

but I get this error

```
An error occurred at line: 18 in the jsp file: /jsp/javaServlet/IDsearch.jsp
JSONObject cannot be resolved to a type
```

Here is my import clause

```
    <%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
    <%@ page import= "java.io.*"  %>
    <%@ page import= "java.net.*" %>
    <%@ page import= "org.json.JSONObject" %>
```

Please give me direction?

Comment: your JSP needs a import clause to find JSONObject. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/239147/how-do-you-import-classes-in-jsp

Comment: <%@ page import="java.util.*,java.io.*,java.net.*, org.json.JSONObject %>    I have this currently

Comment: try one import per clause

Comment: Didn't change the error message. I put my import lines in the question now.

Comment: I suppose the jar that contains JSONObject is inside the WEB-INF/lib folder, right?

Comment: Yes but do I need something in the web.xml to link external libraries?

Comment: if everything you need is inside WEB-INF/lib, no.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using eclipse I was able to add the .jar to the list of libraries the web app could see. Basically right click on the project and select build path then configure build path. From there, you can go to the libraries tab and add JARS using the interface.

After re-exporting it as a war file this seemed to work.