# Pass object from Servlet to JSP -> Can't cast object to specific class

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, casting

I'm trying to pass a object of a specific class from my Servlet to a JSP-File. In the JSP-File i want to cast this object to his specific class (because request.getAttribute("car") returns only a object from type Object. But at this point i get a "Car cannot be resolved to a type"-Error.

(I don't know if there is maybe a betther or modern way to do this, because I'm new to Servlets/JSP and want to lern the basics).

Here is my code

```
@WebServlet(
    name = "Test",
    urlPatterns = {"/test"}
)
public class Test extends HttpServlet {

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {

    try {
        Car car = new Car();
        car.company = "BWMW";
        request.setAttribute("car1", car);
        request.getRequestDispatcher("test.jsp").forward(request, response);

    } catch (ServletException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



}

}
```

test.jsp:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <% Car car = (Car) request.getAttribute("car");
        out.println(car.company); 
        %>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: "Car cannot be resolved to a type" you need to add imports to your JSP: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/239147/how-do-you-import-classes-in-jsp or use `full.package.name.of.YourClass`.

Comment: The key doesn't match when you are calling setattribute and gerattribute method (car1 and car)

Comment: You are both right, thanks a lot!