# The server encountered an internal error () that prevented it from fulfilling this request - tomcat server

Tags: java, security, tomcat

I have a project with Java, I found a Vulnerability and tried to solve it using ESAPI, but when I execute it I found the following problem:

[image]

I added this code:

```
<% import org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils;%>
```

This code-making problem and the rest of the code depends on it.
the first code is :

```
boolean bReportFormat=(request.getParameter("reportFormat")!=null);
f.setGroupingUsed(bReportFormat);
```

and the second code is:

```
<% import org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils;%>
  <% String bReportFormat=(request.getParameter("reportFormat")!=null);
String input = request.getParameter("reportFormat");
String Comment = ESAPI.validator().getValidInput("reportFormat", input, "CommentRegex", 400, false, errorV);
String bReportFormat= ESAPI.encoder().encodeForHTML( Comment );



f.setGroupingUsed(bReportFormat);



%>
```

---

I am using the ESAPI as explained without adding anything else.
Please who has a solution to help, and thanks.

Comment: Syntax error. Fix it. Don't post picture of text here, and especially not links to pictures of text. Post the text.

Answer (score 0):

See [How do you import classes in JSP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/239147/how-do-you-import-classes-in-jsp)
The correct syntax for an import in JSP is

   `<%@ page import="org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils" %>`

You need the `page` keyword and `import=` option, and no semicolon.

The normal <% %> syntax is for defining in-line code -- think of it as injecting code *inside* the body of a Java method. `import` statements are not allowed inside methods -- they must be done at the top of the source file. (Tomcat converts the JSP source into a Java source file.) The `<% page %>` directive is to emit page-level declarations such as Java `import` statements.

Comment: Thanks for your help .
I've done what you said, but the problem is not solved
Are there some files that should be added to working ESAPI?

Comment: @Mohammed - please include more information on what failure you are now getting. If you are seeing the same message, I believe your crosstab.jsp file did not get updated correctly on the server.