# Importing Java Class inside JSP file

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, import

How to import Java class inside JSP file?
`<%@page import="javaname.java"%>` is not working in Eclipse Neon.
Already defined full path still not working.

We have an existing project that the java class is inside of WEB-INF/classes instead of src folder but when we try to do it on another project, we cannot import anymore using the same syntax (<%@ page import="package.javaclass"%>)

Java class:

[image]

JSP:

[image]

Comment: You can check this one here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/239147/how-do-you-import-classes-in-jsp

Comment: Remove the `.java`.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I already replaced into packagename.nameofclass still an error "the import cannot be resolved".

Comment: Do you have automatic builds enabled? Did the JSP revalidate after you saved it? What's the exact error message?

Comment: @nitind Yes, the automatic build is enabled. JSP does revalidate after saving. The exact error is "The Import cannot be resolved".

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it should be:

```
<%@page import="package.nameOfTheYouClass"%>
```

You don't need to add the `.java` ending to the class name.

Comment: I already did that but still an error "the import cannot be resolved".

Comment: Have you checked the path to your class? Can you show your class?

Comment: Uploaded screenshot for your request.

Comment: @MarilouMaala Do you use templates? Is your otp.jsp included in some template?

Comment: No. We didn't use any template.

Answer (score 1):

The `Totp.java` source file doesn't belong in the `WEB-INF/classes` folder, it belongs in the `fa` folder under `src` so that Eclipse will compile it for you. At runtime the server is supposed to find the compiled `Totp.class` file there. I'm guessing that `Totp.java` is not actually in the source folder, meaning this was a correct error message all along.

If you've been adding files to, and directly editing files in, the `WEB-INF/classes` folder, you're doing it wrong. That folder is only ever supposed to hold classes compiled from the source folders like `src` and other resources copied there, by Eclipse, from the source folders.

Comment: I know that the java file should be in the scr folder. But when I placed the java file together with the wsdl files inside the src folder, it seems like they didn't connect to each other. So I decided to move it

Comment: Try putting it back to get past this problem, then open a separate question about that *original* one.

Comment: We have an existing project that the java class is inside of WEB-INF/classes instead of src folder but when we try to do it on another project, we cannot import anymore using the same syntax (<%@ page import="package.javaclass"%>)

Comment: When you say "java class", do you mean an actual compiled `.class` file this time?

Comment: Yes is the answer to your inquiry

Comment: That should probably go into a Class Folder (like a Source Folder, but for .class files), since the WEB-INF/classes folder is only used for final deployment, its contents ignored during development and validation.

Answer (score -1):

check if the name of your class is right and that's it.