# I am getting an error-"Cannot be restored to a type"

Tags: jsp

i am trying to call a method of a class in jsp page but i am getting this error.!

Restro cannot be resolved to a type

My code is

```
<body>

<table border="1">
<th> Name</th>
<th> Email</th>
<th> Subject</th>
<th>  Message</th>
<%
String name=(String)session.getAttribute("Uname");
String email=(String)session.getAttribute("Uemail");
String sub=(String)session.getAttribute("Usub");
String msg=(String)session.getAttribute("Umsg");
Restro r=new Restro();
String result=r.viewFeed(name, email, sub, msg);
out.print(result);
%>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

I will be really grateful if someone could help me!

Comment: Restro needs to be imported: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/239147/how-do-you-import-classes-in-jsp

Comment: Use this <%@ page import ="restro pkg"%>.