# How to use JSTL c:forEach var attribute in a JSP scriplet

Tags: jsp, jstl

I have the following jstl combine with jsp scriplet:

I can used

it doesn't give me an error about variable inventory not defined.

But when I used inside the  loop for the scriplet:

It gives me an error "inventory" cannot be resolved.

Any help or hint would be greatly appreciated it!!

Answer (score 2):

The `var` attribute variable is created in the page scope. To access that with a scriptlet, assuming the type of your variable is `Inventory`, use:

```java
Inventory inventory = (Inventory) pageContext.getAttribute("inventory");
```

See also:

- [How do you import classes in JSP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/239147/how-do-you-import-classes-in-jsp)

But, it's better to not use scriptlets and use EL instead. See:

- [How to avoid Java code in JSP files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files)

Comment: Thank you for the help!!! Greatly appreciated. How do I import this class into the jsp file  "com.models.Inventory"

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/239147/how-do-you-import-classes-in-jsp