# How to calculate difference in months in JSP between date column and current date

Tags: date, jsp, jstl, duration

I have the following JSP code and would like to add a second column for the difference in months between the current date and the first column. The List of ${items} is mapped in the Controller, which is calling the corresponding DAO method. Is there a way to do the calculation in the JSP file?

```
<table class="table">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>First Date</th>
<th>Months</th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
<c:forEach items="${items}" var="item">
<tr>
<td><fmt:formatDate value="${item.firstDate}" pattern="yyyy-MM-dd"/></td>
<td>"Here should be the difference in months between the current date and firstDate"</td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the type of `firstDate` is `LocalDate`, you need to use the following code:

```
<td>${ChronoUnit.MONTHS.betwee(item.firstDate, LocalDate.now())}</td>
```

Make sure you [import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/239147/how-do-you-import-classes-in-jsp) [`java.time.LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) and [`java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html).

The following program can be helpful to you in order to understand the code written above:

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(ChronoUnit.MONTHS.between(LocalDate.parse("2019-08-10"), LocalDate.now()));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
12
```

By any chance, if the type of `firstDate` is `java.util.Date`, I suggest you switch from the [error-prone legacy date-time and formatting API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html) to the modern date-time and formatting API. Learn more about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**

Comment: Thank you Arvind! I forgot to specify that the SDK of the project is 1.7 and LocalDate and  ChronoUnit are not available.

Comment: @alexander java.time with `LocalDate` and `ChronoUnit` has been backported. Get [ThreeTen Backport](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and use the code from this answer with Java 1.7 too.