# Importing IntStream in a jsp resolves to a package

Tags: java, jsp

I'm a java noob and an even bigger noob with jsp's and JBoss and Apache 2.4 (all of which my jsp is using to be served)

I am making a jsp to be an endpoint for a ResultSet-turned-Json, and I have copied another jsp to get started (which works). There are import statements in the jsp such as

```
<%@ page import="java.util.Date" %>
```

And Date works!

But, when I try to use `java.util.stream` or `java.util.IntStream` I get this error:

> `Only a type can be imported. java.util.IntStream resolves to a package`

What am I doing wrong?

---

I have tried many searches on Google, to no avail. Also this SO question: [How do you import classes in JSP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/239147/how-do-you-import-classes-in-jsp) but no dice.

### ***More Info***

I'm following this guide to get a result set to print to json: https://www.baeldung.com/java-jdbc-convert-resultset-to-json - using the instructions for "No external dependencies"

Comment: By the way… The terribly-flawed legacy date-time classes like `java.util.Date` were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. Specifically replaced by `java.time.Instant`.

Comment: Goes to show how old this code is that I have to deal with.

Answer (score 2):

> But, when I try to use java.util.stream or java.util.IntStream I get
> this error:

You should try:

```
<%@ page import="java.util.stream.IntStream" %>
```

Comment: Yup, that worked. Now that I know how stupid my question was, I'll probably go ahead and delete it to avoid the need for someone else to do it with all the red tape. Thanks babanin - sweet thumbnail.